# Express | Routing is messing up css

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I ran into a problem I couldn't find an answer for.
I'm using Express for my website's framerwork and I'm using its routing but it seems to mess up links and files attached to a page.

Here is what I use :

```
app.get('/profile/:name/:age', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.params.name;
  var age = req.params.age;
  someFunction(name, age, function(error, profile) {
    res.render('userprofile', profile);
  });
});
```

The page renders but the links are broken, instead of going to example.com/css/main.css it goes to example.com/profile/(whatever name I went to)/css/main.css so this returns html instead of the css file. Same things for my links.

Note that I can show up that, with css enabled, no problem :

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  res.render('userprofile');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're using relative url's for your CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

If the current (page) url is `/profile/username/`, that translates to:

```
/profile/username/css/main.css
```

Solution? Use absolute url's for resources and links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Right on point, thanks I didn't know that it had to be absolute :)